# is jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement available?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey

I am working on Maven-jersey-Tomcat for rest-api development. but or xml type annotation @XmlRootElement or dependency javax.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement is not working...
I have also attached screen shot as well[image]

Comment: What action are you performing that isn't working? Can you copy the messages from the Console here, as text, instead of just posting a screenshot? How are your rest handlers set up?

Comment: Does the AlienResource class need to be saved?

Comment: Can you show your dependencies in your pom.xml?

Comment: I'm not sure but I think `MessageBodyWriter not found` error can occur when type of response you are sending is not what expected. Please check your configuration of accepts and response type of request. And as I said earlier, this is just a guess. Please add your code and stack trace for proper diagnosis of problem.

Comment: Hi Paul.. Here is pom.xml codes:

Comment: Hi Paul..Dependencies are: jersey-bom, jersey-container-servlet-core, jersey-hk2, jersey-media-json-binding,

Comment: Hi nitind.. Here is console message: getAlien() called....
Jan 04, 2021 7:43:39 AM org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class com.spiderscrawl.demorest.Alien, genericType=class com.spiderscrawl.demorest.Alien.  ........................ Here in above screen shot as you can see that i am trying to get xml response on browser and on conside println command shows getAlien() message called....

Comment: I would switch jersey-media-json-binding for jersey-media-json-jackson.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I instead tried for MediaType.Application_JSON and it works rather XML...Thanks anyway...you helped a lot.....

Answer (score 2):

use these dependency

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
 <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
</dependency>
 
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
 <artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: use this import statement import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

Answer (score 0):

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

Import this `package`, it will work with the above maven dependencies from Ashish bindra.

Note: Hope you are working with Telusko tutorials, I tested with that and it is working fine.